# Parsing multi-form request (iframe)

Tags: java, android, webserver, httpservice, httpserver

I have a httpservice on my android device. So
I send a single file via XMLHttpRequest, if possible, or iframe in every other case.
If I use Google Chrome it works fine and I have no questions, because it uses XMLHttpRequest to send file.
But when I use IE or Opera which send file via iframe I get a problem, because I receive request like below:

```
------------Gg3pxYwLKOqlVLkQwq3Hyn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"; filename="Android.png"
Content-Type: image/png

‰PNG 
some symbols ....
.......................
------------Gg3pxYwLKOqlVLkQwq3Hyn
```

I want to parse it and take filename and file content as binary or base64 without header and footer. Can I parse it by Android's instruments or should use 3rd part library? Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/